# Shelve.open создаёт 3 файла вместо 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь создать файл с данными через shelve.open('filename'), но вместо filename у меня создаётся filename.bak, filename.dat, filename.dir
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `shelve.open('filename.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

Так это ж не ошибка. https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html

> Open a persistent dictionary. The filename specified is the base filename for the underlying database. As a side-effect, an extension may be added to the filename and more than one file may be created.

Comment: А что делать если мне надо 1 файл?

Comment: Вероятно не надо.